# Deleting item from listview by long click in Android error

Tags: java, android, list

I want to add items to appear as **ListView**, and I also want when I long click on a specific item, it should get deleted.

For the adding part, it is working well, but for the deleting part, it doesn't work out.

I think I should add an ArrayList, but I don't know how I can link it with the adapter, so the items that I enter should be put in ArrayList..

```
package com.example.asus.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Adapter;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         final ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
        final ListView myList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listToDo);

        final ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        myList.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        Button addButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                EditText myItem = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
                String value = myItem.getText().toString();
                listAdapter.add(value);
                myItem.getText().clear();


            }
        });
        myList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),((TextView)view).getText().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        myList.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                //Adapter adapter = new Adapter(this, listAdapter);


                listAdapter.remove(String.valueOf(position));
                listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Item deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return false;
            }
        });

    }
}
```

It was working well in the adding part without any error.
Update:

I added

```
listAdapter.remove(String.valueOf(position));
```

instead of

```
listAdapter.remove(position);
```

There is not any error, but when I long click the item, a message appears "Item deleted" as in the toast, but the item still exists on the listview, how can I fix that?

Comment: *//error here at position* - care to share?

Comment: Try this
String value = ((String) myList.getItemAtPosition(position));
listAdapter.remove(myItem);

Comment: There error is "change variable 'listAdapter' type to 'android.widget.ArrayAdapter<android.widget.EditText>' "

Answer (score 4):

Because `listAdapter` is an instance of [ArrayAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter). It do not have any APIs which allow you delete an item based on given position. To delete an item you should you [remove(T)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#remove(T)) API.

By the way when init the `listAdapter` you should pass `arrayList` into constructor.

```
final ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);
```

To delete a selected item

```
arrayList.remove(position);
listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

or

```
listAdapter.remove(arrayList.get(position));
listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```